# What's 'today's green?'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Here is the passage:

While teaching PTE, I came across the passage, and couldn't find *green's* relevant meaning.

> Orville and Wilbur Wright were brothers living in Dayton, Ohio. The two had started making bicycles during the 1890s and had a successful small business selling their Wright Specials for $18 each ***($475 in today’s green).*** This experience with building light, strong machines would prove valuable in the coming years after the brothers’ interest turned to flight.

My guess: it's today's currency notes in green color? Not sure though...

Answer (score 2):

Correct, *green = money* here.

Interestingly, sources vary when explaining the origin:

- the fact that dollar bills are [greenish](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=GREENS&amp=true) (even more so in [past times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money))
- the cockney “greengage” for “wages” ([Source](https://www.learnenglish.de/slang/moneyslang.html))

But the former is the more frequent explanation.